# Django Javascript -- Static js file not running when extended from base.html to a template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

In my current Django project, I have a static javascript file.  It's explicitly loaded as part of my base.html file that I then extend onto each template that's part of the site.  When a template-based page loads, the code from the base.html file is all present, including my javascript file at the bottom of the page; however, none of the javascript itself appears to be run.  Here's the basic setup:

Base.html begins with `{%load staticfiles}` and contains the following line at the very end of the html body `<script src="{% static 'js/maps.js' %}"></script>`

Then any given template begins with `{%extends "base.html"%}`.  After any of these pages load, if I view the source in my browser the `<script src="{% static 'js/maps.js' %}"></script>` line is present right where it should be at the bottom of the page.

Right now maps.js has very little code in it.  I noticed the problem originally because it wasn't loading objects (a google maps map) or responding to actions on the page, but for testing purposes I'm just trying to get it to give me an alert or anything.  I've tried simply having a single `alert();` in the file as well as using $(function(){ alert(); }); to wait until the page has loaded.

Can anyone point out where the issue might be?  I wasn't sure if this was a matter of the order things are loaded on pages or something else I might not be aware of.  It seemed like it could apply to other situations in Django and working with static files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem running linked javascript files in views with ui-router in Angular js. I'm trying to find the old test project I made to squash said bug to see if it could inform this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the jquery library before the maps.js file. 
Also I prefer using

```
$( document ).ready( function() { 

   //your code

} );
```

instead.
Hope it works.

Comment: Try adding all the scripts on another template and then include them on the bottom of your base.html

        {% include 'common/scripts.html' %}
        
        {% block extra_scripts %} {% endblock %}